# Retrieve Parent Child Cub-Child recors in SQL Query

Tags: sql, nested

[Get records containing all the child records in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031000/get-records-containing-all-the-child-records-in-sql-server)

I'm getting an output (from second answer on above said link) as expected, but it's displaying results in below format.

```
<parent id> - <name> - <code> 
<child id> - <name> - <code>
<child id> - <name> - <code>
<child id> - <name> - <code>
<child id> - <name> - <code>
<sub child id> - <name> - <code> 
<sub child id> - <name> - <code> 
<sub child id> - <name> - <code>
```

I want to display the results like in below format.

```
<parent id> - <name> - <code> 
  <child id> - <name> - <code> 
  <child id> - <name> - <code> 
        <sub child id> - <name> - <code> 
        <sub child id> - <name> - <code> 
  <child id> - <name> - <code> 
  <child id> - <name> - <code> 
        <sub child id> - <label> - <code> 
  <child id> - <name> - <code> 
  <child id> - <name> - <code>
```

How can I formulate above said order of display?

Comment: does my answer below help you? Need extra info regarding the  logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Add Recursion column to CTE2 and in the final select statement should look like:

```
SELECT  ID, 
    case when Recursion = 1 then Name
    else replicate(' ', Recursion) + Name end as Name, 
    ParentID, 
    Path
FROM    CTE2
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07faa/28

Note: if you run the code in SQL Server management studio then the spaces will be seen (in SQL Fiddle there may be a default trim option for the results

Comment: the REPLICATE function is the real answer to your question. More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383(v=sql.105).aspx